# Does the "Climbing right turn" instruction of this SID violate the "Climb to 400 feet above DER before turning" requirement?

Tags: faa-regulations, takeoff, climb, departure-sid

I was examining the [LaGuardia Five](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1809/00289laguardia.pdf#nameddest=(LGA)) SID, and I noticed that for runway 13 (Coney Climb) it gives the instruction, immediately after takeoff, "Climbing right turn heading 180 degrees to intercept CRI R-043" (textual description of this SID can be found [here](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1809/00289laguardia_c.pdf#nameddest=(LGA))).

However, as far as I have understood, performing a turn before covering a 400 feet vertical distance above the Departure End of Runway point is not allowed (in other words, turning before covering the Initial Climb Area). Is it implied that the pilot should not perform this turn before meeting the particular requirement?

Comment: I may be missing something, but where does it say "*immediate* right turn" in the SID? I only see regular climb instructions, and instrument departures are always assumed to start with a 400' straight-out climb anyway (see [the IPH, Chapter 1](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/FAA-H-8083-16B_Chapter_1.pdf)). What makes you think that the SID requires you to turn before reaching 400'?

Comment: @Pondlife thank you for your comment, I had forgotten that this is clearly stated in the Instrument Procedures Handbook. Please feel free to post this as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted one.